# Functions inside a static class need the name of the class to be called

Tags: c#, static

I have a class named MyFillerClass in the file MyFillerClass.cs like so  :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace trial
    {
        public static class MyFillerClass
        {
            public static List<string> returnCategoryNames()
            {
                List<string> catNames = new List<string>();
                catNames.Add("one");
                catNames.Add("two");
                catNames.Add("three");
                catNames.Add("Others");
                return catNames;
            }
        }
    }
```

now when i want to call it from somewhere else (like a form class) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace trial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static string lastSelectedCategory;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.DataSource = returnCategoryNames(); //error : The name 'returnCategoryNames' does not exist in the current context
            lastSelectedCategory = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lastSelectedCategory = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("### User choosed " + lastSelectedCategory + " category");
        }
    }
}
```

the line "listBox1.DataSource = returnCategoryNames();" produce an error as indicated in the code ,to fix it i have to adjust it to "listBox1.DataSource = MyFillerClass.returnCategoryNames();".

the question is : in a long program that can add a lot of typing ,can i adjust the class MyFillerClass in such a way that i can just call the function like so :  returnCategoryNames() ?

Comment: I suppose, you should use `MyFillerClass.returnCategoryNames();` it will work. Please try and let me know.

Comment: it does work . but because i tend to use long descriptive function names adding a class name will make the line of code very long sometimes.i just want to avoid extra typing and very long lines of code.

Comment: Ok Thanks, but that's the Framework design! I hope the upcoming version C#6.0 will help you to write smaller lines of code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not in C# up to 5.0. You need to prefix the [static method name with the class name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

However, in [C# 6.0 there will be static using statements available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx). This new language feature will allow you to access directly static classes methods.

Comment: Uhg. I have mixed feelings about that upcoming feature.

Answer (score 2):

Yo can't do it in C# yet. To do it, you need to do a none static class and none static method.

You can do an [extension method](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/261639/Extension-Methods-in-NET).

Answer (score 0):

To call a function from a class you need to have an object created for that class then only you can call the method defined in the class.

In case of static class no need to create any object. you have to direct call the method followed by the class name.

In your case
MyFillerClass.returnCategoryNames();